# Is there an IC chip to toggle through three outputs?

Tags: led, integrated-circuit

I am making a simple circuit (14 LED's that will create a chase effect), however, I wanted to do it without following any tutorials, to test my skills. I ran into a problem. In my circuit, I have all my LED's hooked up so that the first is connected to the fourth, the second to the fifth, the third to the sixth, and so on in a third-connection pattern. I want the LED's to go through a pattern of 1-2-3.

I need a way (I believe that there is an IC chip for it, but I can't find it) to toggle through three outputs when I effect one input. For example, the output pins of the IC chip be connected to the strings of first, second, and third LED. I would have a 555c timer that ticks every so often, and the output signal of the 555c timer would be connected to the input of the IC chip. Each time the IC chip is triggered by the 555c timer, it would switch the signal, from 1, then to 2, then to 3. Is there such an IC chip, and if not, how can I simulate it (I could possibly get by with just alternating one and two LED's instead of three, if there is a circuit or IC chip that would just toggle between two).

Comment: actually, I miss read what pattern you wanted. You simply want 123123, like a marquee?

Comment: @Passerby That is correct; the pattern is 1-2-3-1-2-3. I should have made that more clear, but I was in a rush.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to try a 4017 (CMOS) or 74HC4017 (TTL) Johnson decade counter. ([Philips 74HCT4017 @ Jameco](http://www.jameco.com/1/1/25336-74hc4017-decade-counter-divide-10-decoded-output-dip-16-74hc-series.html)).

You can wire the output of whatever number you want to reset at to the reset pin.

For example you would connect the pulse output of the 555 to pin 13 or 14 (depending on whether you want to trigger when the pulse is low or high), the LED's to the first 3 outputs (pins 3, 2, 4), and output 4 (pin 7) back to reset (15).

Comment: Have added +1 for your answer

Answer (score 3):

As JYelton says - the 4017. Here's the circuit
[image]

Comment: This is mostly correct, but a transistor will be needed, as each output is limited to 15mA, unless you want to share 15mA between 5 leds at a time, which will be fairly dim.

Comment: @passerby this is correct, not just mostly correct. The question asks "I need a way (I believe that there is an IC chip for it, but I can't find it) to toggle through three outputs when I effect one input." That's exactly what the circuit does. As the LEDs are connected in **series** (also stated in the question) the same 15 mA current passes through them - plenty to light them up. Only one output will be active at any time. Your comment seems to imply the LEDs are in parallel and that each LED will somehow get less current.

Comment: Actually, the question does not state series or parallel, nor the forward voltage of the leds, or the source voltage, so assuming on that side also implies that they have between 10 and 15 volts for VDD, as 5 leds in series, even red ones with 2.2V forward voltage, is 11V.

Comment: @JImDearden Actually, my LED's are in parallel with each other. However, I only needed to know the IC that would toggle a sequence between three outputs. I know that there will be problems with the LED's not lighting up properly, but that is the whole point of experimenting and learning.

Comment: And so I can get this clear, this IC chip can work under a regular 9 volt battery, right? Or do I need a resistor to the +V (pin 16).

Comment: @cakeisajoke it works up to 15v, so a 9v will work. No resistor needed on pin 16.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about one, if it isn't a microcontroller, but any counter IC with the two lowest bits sent to a 4-bit demultiplixer would be close.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

555 Timer hooked up to a 4017 Decade Counter. You can hook up ten leds directly, but for a chase effect, you would hook it up as above. You could use just 3 or 6 leds/outputs.

Comment: So, say that I only wanted three LED's instead of 6, like in your schematic; would I just hook up three instead of 6, and that's that, or do I need to change the resistors around?

Comment: The circuit above lights up the LEDs in the following order: 6-5-4-3-2-1-2-3-4-5-6 and so on, while from what I understand from your question you want 1-2-3-1-2-3 etc. So yes, you would have to change the way you wire up the LEDs significantly.

Comment: @cakeisajoke wire mostly the same, but except of simply leaving output 6 empty, you would tie it to the reset pin (pin 15).

Comment: @us2012 I think you are right. My answer is a knight rider/larson scanner bouncing effect. I think op wants a marquee.

Comment: I should give you a -1 just for using a 555!  But I'll be nice, THIS TIME!  :)

Comment: @DavidKessner ? Have something personal against the 555 or?

Comment: @Passerby  I had a very tragic childhood accident involving a 555 that has put me in therapy for the past few decades.  I now travel around the country warning others about the Church of the 555.  :)